# C++ Data Structure to Find Neighbouring Values in Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, multidimensional-array, neighbours

I have a project where I read in an array that has 1 or more dimensions, and for this project I need to be able to determine a given element's neighbours quickly. I do not know the dimensionality ahead of time, and I likewise do not know the size of the dimensions ahead of time. What would be the best C++ data structure to store this data in? A colleague recommended a vector of vectors of vectors of . . ., but that seems incredibly unwieldy.

Comment: What do you mean by neighbours?

Comment: If there was one dimension:
Index x has neighbors x-1 and x+1 ;;;

Two dimensions:
Index (x,y) has neighbors (x-1,y), (x+1,y), (x,y-1), (x,y+1)

etc

Comment: And what is the your input to your program? I guess the dimension of the array and the array elements? (such as 2*3 and 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)?

Comment: Yes, except the data is not in a C++ array; it's in a proprietary wrapper class that I have to extract the data out of.

Comment: You only want orthogonal neighbors? (i.e. in the 2-d case, there are a max of 4) Or do you want the "full neighborhood", where the 2-d case would give you up to 8 neighbors?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the address of which element you need the neighbors for, could you just do pointer arithmetic to find out the neighbors. For example, if p is the location of the element, then p-- is the left neighbor and p++ is the right neighbor.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I need to figure out what to store the data in in the first place such that something like that would be feasible.

Comment: I just realized I forgot to mention something, so I'll copy what I commented above: the data is not in a C++ array; it's in a proprietary wrapper class that I have to extract the data out of.

Comment: so I guess the question to ask then is that what sort of information you need to maintain from the Wrapper class before you can decide on a structure.

Comment: because if you need to lookup something based on a key then a map would work for you better.

Answer (score 0):

Think your multidimensional array as a 1D array. Let the dimension of the array is `d1 * d2 * ....* dn`

Then allocate memory for a  **1D** array, say `A` of size `d1 * d2 * ....* dn`. For example,

```
int *A = new int[d1 * d2 * ....* dn];
```

If you need to store data in the `[i1][i2]...[in]` th index, then store in the following index:

```
A[i1 * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + i2 * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + in]
```

Neighboring elements will be:

```
A[(i1 + 1) * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + i2 * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + in] 
A[(i1 - 1) * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + i2 * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + in] 

A[i1 * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + (i2 + 1) * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + in] 
A[i1 * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + (i2 - 1) * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + in] 

.............................
A[i1 * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + i2 * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + (in + 1)] 
A[i1 * (d2*d3*d4.. *dn) + i2 * (d3*d4*....dn) + ..... + (in - 1)]
```